# Getting a warning "[-Wimplicit-int]"

Tags: c

Getting an error saying

> calculator.c:11:9: warning: type of 'num1' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
> 11 |     int addition(num1, num2)"

The code will still run but wondering why this comes up?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    int addition(num1, num2)
    {
        return num1+num2;
    }

    int subtraction(num1, num2)
    {
        return num1-num2;
    }

    int multiply(num1, num2)
    {
        return num1*num2;   
    }

    float devide(num1, num2)
    {
        return num1/num2;
    }

    printf("Still works");

}
```

Comment: You didn't supply the type for your function arguments. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` when compiling if you use `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: I mean i made it a float so it would give me the correct value, either way I removed the divide section and the problem still persists.

Comment: Where are parameter type declarations?

Comment: FUZION, in `int addition(num1, num2)`, what type is `num1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, do not put your functions *inside* `main`.
Each function should be standalone:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(num1, num2)   // Function BEFORE main, not inside main
{
    return num1+num2;  
}


int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    ....
}
```

---

Secondly, when declaring your functions, give a type to each parameter:

```
int addition(int num1, int num2)   // Declared each parameter as "int"
{
    return num1+num2;  
}
```

---

Finally, for long term code-usability, ***be consistent and correct*** with names.

```
// You named the first two functions addition and subtraction
// so this one should be "multiplication", not "multiply"!
// A sudden change in naming convention means poor design!
int multiply(num1, num2)


// The proper spelling of the operation is "divide" or "division"
// You will make other programmers jobs extremely difficult
// if they cannot tell what function this is, because of a misspelling.
float devide(num1, num2)
```

---

Putting all these changes together:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int addition(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}

int subtraction(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1-num2;
}

int multiplication(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1*num2;   
}

float division(int num1, int num2)
{
    return (float)num1/num2;
}

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    printf("Still works");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah alright all works now, thanks a bunch

Comment: Thanks for the edit too!  My first few days learning this so this is helpful, thanks again.